# Set line_item list value in before Load of form in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to update the date of a field if "item_id is 900",

```
define(['N/record', 'N/search'],
    function(record, search){
        function salesorderbeforeload(context){
            var currentRecord = context.newRecord;
           var sublistName="item";
           var start_Date="custcol_atlas_contract_start_date";
          var end_date="custcol_atlas_contract_end_date";
            var lines = currentRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'});
           log.debug({title:'lines',details:lines});     
            for (var i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
                var itemId = (currentRecord.getSublistValue({
                     sublistId: "item",
                     fieldId: "item",
                     line: i
                }));     
var value=itemId;
             if(value=="900")
                  {
                  currentRecord.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: "item",
                            fieldId: "custcol_atlas_contract_start_date",
                            line: 0,
                            value: "2021-09-09T07:00:00.000Z"
                        });
                  }
            }
    
        }
        return{
            beforeLoad: salesorderbeforeload
        };
    }
);
```

The above code will fetch the line item id as value , and if the value is 900 it will set the date to the following
Evrything is working perfectly except for this code,

```
  currentRecord.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: "item",
                            fieldId: "custcol_atlas_contract_start_date",
                            line: 0,
                            value: "2021-09-09T07:00:00.000Z"
                        });
```

```
        record=currentRecord.setSublistValue({
                            sublistId: "item",
                            fieldId: "quantity",
                            line: 0,
                            value: "3"
                        });
```

Even the quantity is not updating.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update existing records so that ultimately will be your issue.
You may be able to fix this in a before submit event when the record is saved or in a Client Event script.

As far as the code supplied though you are not advancing the line index. You should have:

```
currentRecord.setSublistValue({
     sublistId: "item",
     fieldId: "custcol_atlas_contract_start_date",
     line: i, // NOT 0
     value: "2021-09-09T07:00:00.000Z"
});
```

but after that is your custom field an actual date time or is it a text field?

if you are trying to store a date you'll need to parse your ISO formatted date string to an actual date. This is different from SS1 where dates had to be date formatted strings.

As far as item groups go the custom field needs to be configured to save the value for group items.

There is a checkbox, "Store with Item Groups" on the field definition

[image]

Comment: Hi bknights, Thanks for the comments. Yes, the line is : line: i, // NOT 0. since i am trying it in particular line, I used the line :0. and as for the second point yes I am storing it in datefield.I tried to update quantity  but quantity also not updating .

Comment: hi Bknights, But as for group items the above is not working.any other way to update group items.

Comment: Do you mean an item group?

Comment: yes for item group @bknight

Comment: Updated my answer to what I assume is the item group issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try saving the record after all the updates?

You can try this approach where you load the record first, then check for your conditions, accordingly update the fields and then perform a record save.

```
var objRecord = record.load({
   type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
   id: 157,
   isDynamic: true,
});
```

Then you can iterate over the line items. Use **FOR LOOP**

```
for(var j=0; j<numLines; j++) {

   //fetch the item_id using getCurrentSublistValue

   if(item_id == 900) {
      //Perform the setSublistValue
   }
}
```

And finally,

```
objRecord.save();
```

Give this a try, even I'm not sure of this approach. Let me know in case of any issues.